# Analysis real , continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Given a $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ with the property that if $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $f$ is a bounded function. Show that $X$ is compact.

Comment: Is "limited" bounded?

Comment: be careful, the popular map $f: \mathbb{R} \to \left(-\pi/2, \pi/2\right)$ defined by $f(x) = \tan^{-1}(x)$ is limited ( bounded in your sense ) but $\mathbb{R}$ is no compact !

Comment: yes, $f(X)$ is bounded.

Comment: I think this is a fair and interesting question; I would not close it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's show this by contradiction. If $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ is not compact, then it is either unbounded and so $f(x)=x$ is an unbounded function, or it is not closed. In the later case, choose $a\in\overline{X} - X.$ Then $f(x)=1/(x-a)$ is continuous on $X$ but unbounded.